How important is grading around a foundation if there is no basement?
I'm looking to put some storage bins next to our garage.
How important is it to grade the soil away from the foundation of the garage if there is no basement under it? I wouldn't run it to the garage, but is it OK to have it flat or does the soil around bins still need to slope away?

No basement. But is there a crawl space? Or is really just a slab?

Grading/a slope allows water to flow away faster and lets the ground dry out.   While flat spots would not hurt a slab, it might allow the ground around the bins to get muddy.  A small platform will keep the grade and keep the bins out of the dirt.

It's really just a slab, no crawl space. That said I appreciate the thought of not allowing pooling.

Put them on pallets, and clear them out on a regular basis. Have stored a lot of totes outside in weather, they all break down/get eaten.
Keep the grade away from and allow the water that accumulates to move naturally and you won't have an issue.

This could work in many areas. However in those places where termites are prevalent, pallets are a feast and invitation for them to come to your home.  Don't do it.  Use something that termites don't eat. One could treat the soil under the pallets, but that is temporary and using termiticide is regulated. Best bet concrete stepping stones and grade away from the house.

@RMDman  There are also plastic pallets.  Not as common probably cost more and not given away as often.  Even with no termites, wood pallets tend to rot if left on the ground(dirt).

I'm not concerned about them breaking down. The bins will be metal compost bins.

Instead of pallets, a less termite-friendly solution may be to use a small section of cellular confinement system (geocell), filled with $57 stone.  They can be had in a variety of thicknesses—the thickest I've seen is 8" and you can always stack if you need more height.

I can never find that near me- wanted it for my walkways.
